# sp_server_diagnostics in suspended state

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In our environment we have cluster set up. As per my little knowledge **sp_server_diagnostics** should be in running status and it is useful for health checkup of cluster. It seems like someone suspended that SPID or something else. So, how can I restart this? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's normal. see more details here [sp_server_diagnostics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878233(v=sql.110).aspx). A suspended status just means that at the moment you're calling it, it's waiting on resources and will restart when it's ready.

Try to run `sp_server_diagnostics` from SSMS it showing the Result sets for all resources which are running. Unless you have some other indications that this thing is problematic, but it's not.